# Pandas - Adding auto - increment value to Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, range

I have a Dataframe in which I would like to add a new column that has numbers added to it as a column in increments. This is more like a id (with an incremental update)

However I would like this id column to start from value stored in a variable called `max_id`

```
df['id'] = [x for x in range(max_id, max_id + len(df) + 1)]
```

This throws an error

```
ValueError: Length of values (7649) does not match length of index (7648)
```

For example if max_id value is 100, I would like the `df['id']` to start from 101 and go on for how many ever rows are there in the Dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I get you, but you could just use `np.arange`:

```
df['id'] = np.arange(max_id + 1, max_id + len(df) + 1)
```

Or:

```
df['id'] = np.arange(max_id, max_id + len(df)) + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try using [`pd.RangeIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.RangeIndex.html).

```
df['id'] = pd.RangeIndex(max_id, max_id + len(df)) + 1
```